# How to disable validation for specific row Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I code a project with ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework. I have a controller which has one action(Save action which commit changes to database).

I want to bypass "Answer" property out of validation without using DataAnnotations. In View, i tried some code but failed. Because of my dynamic modelling structure i cant use DataAnnotations.

So how can i disable a specific property and make this property out of validation?

Here is my model:

```
  [Table("Answers")]
    public class Answer
    {
        [Key]
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "***")]
        public string Answer { get; set; }

    }
```

The property which must be out of validation.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(mo => mo.Answers[j].Answer, new { style = "width: 100%", data_val = false })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can simply disable client side validation in the Razor view prior to render the field and re-enable client side validation after the field has been rendered.**

This will work :-

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
@Html.TextAreaFor(mo => mo.Answers[j].Answer, new { style = "width: 100%", data_val = false })
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get this errow: CS1502: 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'

Comment: @Fatih1453..it is working fine on my machine..just check there must be some other problem instead..

Comment: Thanks. I'll turn to you.